# Setting todays date as a cut off for a Find search VBA

Tags: vba, date, excel, find

I'm trying to set the rng to do a search of the worksheet to determine if there are any dates before or including today's date and if there isn't to move to the next worksheet.

I have the below code that works exactly as I want to collect any rows that are before or inclusive of todays date to the worksheet that the 'macro button' is located, but if there aren't any dates that fall in to that criteria it is going to return an error, and I want to remove this error if anyone else opens the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCtrl As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long, rng As Range
Dim tdate As Date

tdate = Date

Set wsCtrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collate Info")

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name = "Collate Info" Then GoTo nextsheet
With ws
    lrow = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rng = .Range("I2:I" & lrow).Find(what:="<tdate")
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo nextsheet
    .Range("I2:I" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & tdate
    .Range("I3:I" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    wsCtrl.Range("A" & wsCtrl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
nextsheet:
Next

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried a few other variations on setting the .Find line and can't seem to get it right, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I get an error on your Find; I changed to: 'Set rng = .Range("I2:I" & lrow).Find(What:=CDate(tdate))' but that only finds dates matching today - not earlier... I will look some more, but you may need an alternate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to find the min values in the range of dates and compare with today's date.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range("I1:I" & lrow)) > DateValue(Date) Then GoTo nextsheet
```

Hope this helps =]

Comment: This code is working perfectly thank you ! 

It took me a bit of trial and error to get it working because it seemed to be returning a lot of errors wherever I put it in my code, then I realised that in my test sheet I didn't actually have any Dates where it was checking thus leading to the error. 

Cheers Again !